# Removing all namespaces in the xml and valid per wsdl

Tags: wsdl, xsd, xml-namespaces, soapui

Again I am back with a question related to the same wsdl, this time wanted to remove all namespaces in the request, and conforming to the wsdl.

The same wsdl tripservice wsdl from [the link](http://www.developers-blog.org/blog/de/2010/03/03/Webservice-testing-with-soapUI) ,simply replace the "from" element with the below.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="from" nillable="true">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
```

Using soapui we know that the below request xml conforms to wsdl.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:trip="http://trip.price.service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <trip:getTripPrice>
      <trip>
        <adults>9</adults>
        <duration>9</duration>
        <from xsi:nil="true" />
        <rooms>3</rooms>
      </trip>
    </trip:getTripPrice>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I removed almost all namespaces from the request, however not able to remove xsi namespace from the request, so as to conform to wsdl

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header/>
  <Body>
    <getTripPrice xmlns="http://trip.price.service">
      <trip xmlns="">
        <adults>9</adults>
        <duration>9</duration>
        <from xsi:nil="true" />
        <rooms>3</rooms>
      </trip>
    </getTripPrice>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

How to remove xsi namespace as well, still valid as per the wsdl?

Comment: No wsdl can tell you not to send the xsi namespace, or any other namespace.

Comment: ok. so if we have any attribute with namespace, always we should send that? In case of element we know that if we add xmlns="url corresponding to namespace", along with the element no need to mention the namespace along with the element.

Comment: namespace prefix definition attributes cannot change the compliance of a message with a WSDL/schema. One the actual namespace assigned to the node itself via xmlns= or a prefix matters.

Comment: i wanted to remove the prefix alone ie instead of xsi:nil = "true" just nil="true", with some xmlns = defenition

Comment: why? That can't change compliance. The dataset is identical either way. I doubt that soapui has anything to help you with this.

Comment: sure. Our actual wsdl request/response xml structure is big with a lot of namespace prefix definition attributes. We want to reduce the number of characters that we send as response, by changing 'prefix:name="some"' to just 'name="some"'. This will help us a lot considering the number of characters that is reduced in the response. It defenitely will be an advantage from network,bandwidth point of view.

Comment: Oh, that's different. You didn't say that in your question. What technology are you using to generate soap requests in production? And what about just turning on gzip?

Comment: Yeah. My question was not clear. I use xslt to generate soap responses, using output methode="xml".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic XML processing question, "How do you control the use and production of namespace prefixes in XML producer 'x'"? In your case, according to the comments, 'xml producer X is xslt.' It will then depend on what implementation of XSLT you are using and whether it has any options to control this particular behavior.

In general, xslt takes the usual attitude that namespace prefixes are just syntactic sugar, and does not offer convenient mechanisms for controlling their use. You may be able to encourage it make more use of prefixes by declaring them at the top of your XSLT definition.

I recommend compression as the real solution to reducing bandwidth usage.

Comment: Thanks. I just need the above xml file(the xml which starts with Envelope and not soapenv:Envelope), modified so that instead of xsi:nil="true", it will have nil="true"(with some namespace declaration may be)

Comment: from this link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp, we know that "Defining a default namespace for an element saves us from using prefixes in all the child elements." All I need is how define a default namespace for an attribute?